# Removing header from a formatted string

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a formatted log file I'm trying to parse; the file is divided in sections with an header and the data inside each section is formatted with JSON like follows. [Link to an extract of the log file here](https://pastebin.com/kxUqqEmY)

```
[UnityCrossThreadLogger]1/8/2019 7:49:19 PM
==> Deck.GetDeckLists(112):
{

  "jsonrpc": "2.0",

  "method": "Deck.GetDeckLists",

  "params": {},

  "id": "112"

}
```

My issue here is manipulating the whole string in a way I get to the section I want and there strip the meaningless data and parse the remaining through `Newtonsoft JSON`. For now I'm cutting everything I don't need using this function, since the log file is in chronological order and only the latest occurrence of the entry is needed:

```
//Cut the whole log to the last entry
    private static string CutLog(string fromWhereToCut)
    {
        string log = GetLog();
        //In this case fromWhereToCut would be "Deck.GetDeckLists"
        string s = log.Substring(log.LastIndexOf(fromWhereToCut));

        return s;
    }
```

The problem is the fact i**t leaves the header in place I need to remove** before deserializing the JSON and **it's prone to breaking because the name of the sections aren't that unique** and they could be repeated further down as non-header titles (as can be seen in my example). Furthermore I don't know how to stop at the end of the section I need before another one begins.

I thought RegEx could be used but this seems way to big even for a RegEx and maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Would it be possible to look after the first occurence of '{' ?

Comment: `string s = log.Substring(log.LastIndexOf(fromWhereToCut) + fromWhereToCut.Length);`?

Comment: @MikNiller as you can see in the Pastebin (especially in the last section) it's way more complicated than that.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed that would leave me with a variable number of characters (the part between parentheses "112") that changes at each iteration of the log file, meaning once I could get (112) and another (1).

Comment: I see, then another idea could be to look for [ or { , when one of them is found then continue searching the string for the matching character of same type and then extract the data between the two as json, continue with that until the end of the string. Proberly not very efficient, and a regex master would most likely have a better solution
You need to keep track of additional { [ inside the block you are searching by keeping some kind of refcount

Comment: @nicktheone Then call `Substring` again on the result and look for the first occurrence of "{".

Comment: @MikNiller feels like a drag but it's the same conclusion I reached unfortunately without using RegEx.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed that's a good idea to strip the remaining header but unfortunately I don't know how to face the problem the result of `LastIndexOf` on the header name may not be last instance in the file, as seen in the example above where "Deck.GetDeckLists" is repeated inside the section itself.

Comment: When Newtonsoft JSON throws an exception that it cannot parse does it give the line number where it cannot parse? If so then maybe you can have a try catch that tries to parse, catches the exception, and removes the line where the exception occurred until it gets valid json and is able to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Log is the same as [the one found in PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/kxUqqEmY), this deserializes fine.
I'm using a support class (**`JSON_Logs`**) to contain the extracted data.
The `JSON` is read from a file in this simulation.

Reading the structure of the data, the most probable candidate to identify the start of the actual data, is the recurring string `"Deck.GetDeckLists"`. In the parsing method it's assigned to a variable called  **`excludedSection`**.
The data starts right after the last one of those string. I'm using **`logFile.LastIndexOf(excludedSection)`** to find the index of the last of these entries, then use this index to identify the first data structure.

[JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) is then used to deserialize the data into a List of class objects.
I didn't find any problem during the deserialization process.

```
string searchString = "Deck.GetDeckLists";
List<JSON_Logs.Header> jsonLogs = ParseJsonLog(searchString, "JSON_Logs.txt");

private List<JSON_Logs.Header> ParseJsonLog(string excludedSection, string fileName)
{
    string logFile = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

    int refIndex = logFile.LastIndexOf(excludedSection);
    logFile = logFile.Substring(logFile.IndexOf("[", refIndex));

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSON_Logs.Header>>(logFile);
}
```

Support class:

```
public class JSON_Logs
{
    public class Header
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string resourceId { get; set; }
        public int deckTileId { get; set; }
        public MainDeck[] mainDeck { get; set; }
        public object[] sideboard { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastUpdated { get; set; }
        public bool lockedForUse { get; set; }
        public bool lockedForEdit { get; set; }
        public bool isValid { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainDeck
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need. :) Actually, regex finds json in *all* sections, but I included getting only last section (`matches[matches.Count - 1]`). Since JToken doesn't have `TryParse` method, you have to use try/catch:

```
static void ParseLog()
{
    var s = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\log.json");
    var pattern =
        @"(?s)(?'header'\[\w+\]\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(A|P)M\r\n" +
        @"<?==>?.+?\r\n)" +
        @"(?'body'.+?)(?=$|\[\w+\]\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(A|P)M)";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        JToken last_json = null;
        try
        {
            var text = matches[matches.Count - 1].Groups["body"].Value;
            last_json = JToken.Parse(text);
            WriteLine(last_json.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("No matches found");
    }
}
```